# Why doesn't this webpage work in Internet Explorer only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I don't usually have access to Internet Explorer but right now I did and I checked out our website on Internet Explorer and it fails to show some pages, for example this: http://www.listicle.co/list/user/post.php?listid=607. I enabled the debugger on IE and I've been trying to fix these issues for a while but today I'm getting different errors:

```
HTML1509: Unmatched end tag.
post.php, line 512 character 2

HTML1509: Unmatched end tag. 
post.php, line 1423 character 8

SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery.min.js, line 5 character 6420

SCRIPT87: Invalid argument. 
jquery.min.js, line 5 character 6420
```

The problem is that I don't think that there is any unmatched tag. I also thought this could be a problem with jQuery but I downgraded jQuery to be 1.10... version as suggested by someone else. I also tried enabling HTML shim or shiv and it didn't help either. Can someone with IE please help me debug this issue? I'd highly appreciate it. This is so confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you [validated](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.listicle.co%2Flist%2Fuser%2Fpost.php%3Flistid%3D607&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) your xhtml?

Comment: Try the html5 doctype

Comment: What version of IE and jQuery do you use? `jQuery 2.0` not supports `IE<9`

Comment: @Murali: “I also thought this could be a problem with jQuery but I downgraded jQuery to be 1.10... version as suggested by someone else.”

Comment: Always run your site through something like http://validator.w3.org/check and work your way through the noise (424 errors) :)

Answer (score 7):

`<div>` is not allowed inside `<p>`. IE is auto-correcting your HTML and it is producing unexpected results when it comes to the JavaScript.

Comment: Hi, I fixed all the trivial HTML issues as well. However, I'm still getting the same problem. It seems to me that this line in the jquery library is the issue: `return null!=t?t:e.text`. Anymore ideas?